# Edit object in vector

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

How can i edit a object in a vector?

Right now my vector is `vector<PCB> M3M;`

Inside it are a few objects from my class below.

```
class PCB
{
public:

    void setPID (int a)
    {
        PID = a;
    }
    int retrievePID()
    {
        return PID;
    }

    int retrieveLimit()
    {
        return Limit;
    }
    void setLimit (int a)
    {
        Limit = a;
    }
    int retrieveBase()
    {
        return Base;
    }
    void setBase (int a)
    {
        Base = a;
    }
    int retrieveHoleTrueOrFalse()
    {
        return HoleTrueOrFalse;
    }
    void setHoleTrueOrFalse (int a)
    {
        HoleTrueOrFalse = a;
    }

private:
    int PID;
    int Limit;
    int Base;
    int HoleTrueOrFalse;
};
```

How would i be able to edit the PID part in any place i choose in my object?

For example i want to set a new PID in my vector at M3M[4]. How do i go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`M3M[4].setPID(<new PID>);`

Comment: Ah i thought i had to push the pcb class. Thanks!

Comment: @sonicboom, a vector's [] operator returns a *reference* to the object contained, so it can be modified in place.

Answer (score 1):

You also can have an iterator that can point to an element in your array and set a new PID to that. Example:

```
std::vector<PCB>::iterator it = M3M.begin();
//this will advance your iterator by 3
it += 3;
it->setPID(5); // this will set the 3rd element's PID to 5
```

Keep in mind that your vector needs to have at least 4 elements in order for the code above to execute. In order to you fill your vector, you can use push_back() method of your vector.

```
M3M.push_back(PCB(0));
M3M.push_back(PCB(1));
M3M.push_back(PCB(2));
M3M.push_back(PCB(3));
M3M.push_back(PCB(4));
```

Comment: The question is about `vector<PCB>`, so your `M3M.push_back(new PCB(0));` is wrong as it pushes back pointers.  Just ``M3M.push_back(PCB(0))` (or better yet for C++11 use `emplace_back`).